# Facing issue while uploading and saving the documents in Sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-2013

i am facing issue while uploading and saving the documents in Sharepoint document library as "The file PolicyMemoandGuidelinesLibrary/Team Member List.xls has been modified by i:0#.f|membership|*********** on 12 Dec 2019 01:32:47 -0800". But it was not modified by anyone. For all the documents with any user we are uploading we are facing the same issue. Please give the solution for this. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: is there any workflow getting executed upon file creation?

Comment: Yes when the document has uploaded workflow will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow might be causing the issue, as workflow is triggered as soon as you upload the document, and when you fill in form and hit save a workflow action might have checked out the document already. try disabling the workflow then upload the document to check if that Workflow is  this issue, If so, you can configure workflow to run on Item modification.